# How to know the timestamp of json file stored under web-app inside sevlet & jsp?

Tags: jsp

I have my json file stored under web-app. I am reading the json file like below...

```
InputStream istream = request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("courses.json");
JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(istream);
```

But before reading the entire json file from a servlet/jsp I want to know the timestamp(modified time) of the json file. How to do this?
I do not have handle of File object otherwise I would have accessed the timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy enough to get a File object if you know the relative path of the file inside your webapp.

```
File file = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("courses.json"));
Date date = new Date(file.lastModified());
```

If you're deploying your app as a war file, your container will probably extract it to a temporary directory, so the timestamp will be the deployment time. In that case, I'm not sure if knowing the modified date would be useful in any way.

Comment: @Tap-in case my application is already deployed and I re-upload the JSon file and assuming that it picks the change then will I get last modified time or the old deployment time? I am asking this question since if it requires redeploying the application then I think I can skip doing further changes.

Comment: @Prakash, if you're dropping the file in place after the app has been deployed, I would expect you to see the real last modified time.